# SSIS For Each All Packages

Tags: foreach, ssis, ssms

I am attempting to execute each package within my project, but the only clear directions I have found are 10 years old at: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/executing-ssis-packages/

Is there a more up to date way to accomplish this?

Comment: Also, you can use SQL Agent with different steps for each package.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a Master Package which execute all the packages you need using execute package task?

Comment: Executing the tasks in series?

Comment: what Arun is describing is done in the control flow, and can be done in series or parallel.  Look at the Execute Package Task.